# Com Port Terminology?

Tags: serial-port, terminology

i'm building a UI using a com ports, and i'm trying to write labels to distinguish between the com port and the com port's port number... ?

for example, i'm using Com Port 3, and it's set to 5331.  what is the 5331?  how can i label the two different?

Comment: The last century called, and they want their hardware back.

Comment: What does "it's set to 5331" mean?

Comment: What platform are we talking here? At least put such things in your tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Google (I don't know), port 5331 might an IP port used by Serproxy.

The hardware port for a serial port on a PC is usually something like 3f8 or 2f8 (hex), or 3e8 for COM3.

> i'm just searching for appropriate labels for the input text fields where the user will enter these numbers

In my opinion, a name like "COM3", which identifies local hardware, is appropriate in the configuration UI for the server which has the COM port hardware (in the configuration of the client, connecting to a remote COM port, you might instead want to identify the remote COM port using any other arbitrary name).

The terms "Network port" and "Network address" aren't bad. They might be better (more understandable to a non-technical user) than "Proxy". You could also, I think, say "UDP port" or "TCP port" (depending on which protocol it is), and maybe "IPv4 address" for the machine (or let people specify the machine name and/or localhost instead of the IP address).

Comment: yes, i'm using Serproxy.  do the following labels make sense? Com Port:3, Network Port:5331, Network Address:127.0.0.1.  or maybe they should be called Proxy Port and Proxy Address?

Comment: 5331 is an [IP port number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers). Serial port hardware on a PC has an [I/O address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IO_address) like 3f8 which is the operand of `in` and `out` opcodes. What is your question?

Comment: You seem to be talking about some kind of [COM port redirector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_serial_port).

Comment: ok.  i'm just searching for appropriate labels for the input text fields where the user will enter these numbers.  i'm using an proxy application that allows AIR to communicate to Arduino using TinkerProxy:  http://code.google.com/p/tinkerit/wiki/TinkerProxy

Comment: @TDI1978 I edited my answer to try to answer you latest comment.